# Stocks and Shares System - Simulation

Tags: math, economics, pawn

I'm creating a system for an online game written in an uncommon language (PAWN), similar to C.

I've done some research and found some good information however it's not what I am fully looking for.

In the game there are several industries that I want there to be stocks and shares on.

For example:

Police Department
Fish Market
Housing Market

The volatility of shares is how much swing (+/-) in price change. The higher the volatility, the higher the swing.

In my game the price of each industry will update every minute.

An industry will will bankrupt when it reaches a minimum price per share.
An industry stock will split when it reaches a maximum price per share.

Example:

- Police Dept. - (Bankrupt every 220 price updates) (Stock Split every 660 price updates - if it doesn't bankrupt before then)
- Fish Industry - (Bankrupt every 1000 price updates) (Stock Split every 220 price updates - if it doesn't bankrupt before then)
- House Market - (Never Bankrupts)

I've found a function and altered it to the desired coding language which factors in volatility.

```
Float:GenerateNextPrice(stockid)
{
    if(stockid < 0 || stockid >= sizeof(gStockMarket)) return -1.0; // 

    new Float:rnd; 
    MRandFloatRange(0, 1.0, rnd); // generate number, 0 <= x < 1.0

    new Float:old_price = gStockMarket[stockid][gCurrentStockPrice];
    new Float:volatility = gStockMarket[stockid][gStockVolatility]; // A stable stock would have a volatility number of perhaps 2. A volatility of 10 would show some pretty large swings.
    new Float:change_percent = 2 * volatility * rnd;

    if (change_percent > volatility)
    {
        change_percent -= (2 * volatility);
    }
    new Float:change_amount = (old_price / 100) * change_percent;
    new Float:new_price = old_price + change_amount;
    return new_price;
}
```

This function factors in volatility however the higher the volatility the more the swing.

How would I function where it replicates price increases/decreases but after a certain amount of calls it to eventually bankrupt or split as above?

I understand this may be confusing and happy to answer questions.

Comment: Would the [tag:pawn] tag be appropriate here?

Comment: Yes but there's not a lot of threads on this and didn't think it would the best choice to waste a tag, although the language is similar to C.